# What type should return a Server Side Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

So I just started using the `NextPage` type provided by Next.js while writing components because I was explained it's a very good practice, but it works only on **client side** components. In other words this **server component** throws an error because it's an `async await`.

*The component*:

```
const Page: NextPage = async () => {
  const { products }: { products: CoffeeInterface[] } = await getData(
    "/products"
  )

  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col bg-gradient-to-t from-slate-300 via-slate-200 to-gray-200">
      <SearchCoffee />
      <div className="flex gap-10 w-full">
        <FiltersDropdown />
        <CoffeesList coffees={products} />
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}

export default Page
```

*The error*:

```
Type '() => Promise<JSX.Element>' is not assignable to type 'NextPage'.
  Type '() => Promise<JSX.Element>' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}> & { getInitialProps?(context: NextPageContext): {} | Promise<{}>; }'.
    Type '() => Promise<JSX.Element>' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
      Type 'Promise<Element>' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, keyts(2322)
```

What type should a Server Side Component return, if any? Or should I just write the server components as basic functions without mentioning the type?

I'm using Next.js `13.4`.

Comment: Hi AnnaEG, have you checked the below answers you are given? Please accept the first most helpful one whenever you think your problem is solved, by clicking on the check button next to it.

Comment: Hi! Thanks, sorry, this was my first post on StackOverflow.

Thank you all for help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NextPage` is used for page components in the `pages` directory of Next.js (the initial way of setting up routes). In the `app` directory since Next.js 13, the default export of a [`page.tsx`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/page) could have this type:

```
// app/page.tsx

interface PageProps {
  params: { slug: string };
  searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
}
export default function Page({ params, searchParams }: PageProps) {
 // ...
}
```

`params` and `searchParams` are the only type you can provide, and those will be passed to your component by Next.js. If you don't need them, you can avoid defining them. The return type is most of the time [inferred](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) by TypeScript, so you don't have to type it.

For non-page components, you should type them as any function, again, most of the time, you only need to type its `props` if it has, the return type being [inferred](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html).

And you are using an `async` page where you fetch data in the component body, you could do so:

```
// app/page.tsx

interface PageProps {
  params: { slug: string };
  searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
}
export default async function Page({ params, searchParams }: PageProps) {
 // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is `NextPage` type:

```
/**
 * `Page` type, use it as a guide to create `pages`.
 */
export type NextPage<Props = {}, InitialProps = Props> = NextComponentType<
  NextPageContext,
  InitialProps,
  Props
>
```

I think it is meant to be used for pages directory as the note says. `InitialProps` might refer to the props that passed from the serverside functions (getServerSideProps, getStaticProps) which do not exist in `app` directory. In server components, its type will inferred automatically like this

if you have this page:

```
  const page = async ({}) => {...}
```

its type will be

```
  // if you have props, {} will be populated with props
  const page: ({}: {}) => Promise<JSX.Element>
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is throw by the typescript because you are usin async await in react component so you have to define **What the type of result is return from the react function**

Try This:

```
const Page: NextPage = async (): Promise<JSX.Element> => {
{/* your code */}
}
```