# Error occurred prerendering page while using component & SSR in pages in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I am getting this error while deploying my next js project in vercel.

`Error occurred prerendering page "/bollywood". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error`

I have this code in in the /bollywood/page.jsx file

```js
import Hero from '@/components/Hero'
import Page_reuseable from '@/components/Page_reuseable'
import Subscribe from '@/components/Subscribe'
import React from 'react'

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <>
      <Hero link={'category/bollywood'} />
      <Page_reuseable category={"Bollywood"} />
      <Subscribe />
    </>
  )
}
```

and the Hero and Page_reuseable component has these code

```js
//components/Hero.jsx


async function fetch_data(link) {
    const req = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DEVELOPMENT_BACKEND_URL}/${link}?limit=1`, { credentials: "include", headers: { "x-api-key": process.env.API_KEY }, cache: "no-cache" })
    const res = await req.json()
    if (res.status == 'success') {
        return res.posts[0]
    } else {
        return []
    }
}

export default async function Hero({ link }) {
    const data = await fetch_data(link)

    return (
        <>
          //jsx
        </>
    )
}



//component/Page_reuseable.jsx

async function fetchData(category, limit) {
    const req = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DEVELOPMENT_BACKEND_URL}/category/${category}?limit=${limit}`, { credentials: 'include', headers: { "x-api-key": process.env.API_KEY }, cache: "no-cache" })
    const res = await req.json()
    if (res.status === 'success') {
        return res.posts;
    } else {
        return [];
    }
}


export default async function Page_reuseable({ category }) {

    let limit = 11

    const data = await fetchData(category, limit)

    return (
        <>
              //jsx
        </>
    )
}
```

Now I don't know what is the problem. I am using those component in other pages and it is giving the same error for every page while `generating static page` while deploying in vercel (working fine locally).

I provide the error log if needed below

```js
Error: Unsupported Server Component type: {...}
    at em (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:131932)
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:142926
    at Array.toJSON (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:146504)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at eR (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:134889)
    at eP (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:135332)
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:338:14)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:146956)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
TypeError: i is not iterable
    at i (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/231.js:1:6898)
    at o (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/231.js:1:1213)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
TypeError: i is not iterable
    at i (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/231.js:1:6898)
    at o (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/231.js:1:1213)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Error occurred prerendering page "/bollywood". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: i is not iterable
    at i (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/231.js:1:6898)
    at o (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/231.js:1:1213)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

   Generating static pages (8/16) 
[]
[]
[]

// getting this error as well
TypeError: i is not iterable
    at i (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/231.js:1:6898)
    at o (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/231.js:1:1213)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
TypeError: i is not iterable
    at i (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/231.js:1:6898)
    at o (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/231.js:1:1213)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Error occurred prerendering page "/dollywood". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
```

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76446101/what-type-should-return-a-server-side-component?

Comment: I solved it. I have a api_key & ip address whitelisting in my backend and I am not including the necessary headers (api_key) in the request header. That's I am getting that error.