# Server Side Component return type when it is async in NextJS 14

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In NextJS 14, the [example given](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#fetching-data-on-the-server-with-fetch) in the docs is within the Page component, which I usually type as `NextPage`. This type doesn't accept `async await` server component.

Similarly, what I tend to do is to wrap my own component and I always typed them as `FunctionComponent<MyProps>`. This also doesn't work on async await server component that is given in the example.

What should the type be in this case instead of `FunctionComponent` / `NextPage`?

```
// FunctionComponent doesn't work here, TS error:  
// Type 'Promise<Element>' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, keyts(2322)
export const Header: FunctionComponent<HeaderProps> = async ({
  handleSidebarOpen,
}) => {
  const user = useUserSession();
  const userCredit = await getCredit(user.id);
```

Another example for NextPage:

```
// FunctionComponent doesn't work here, TS error:  
// Type '() => Promise<JSX.Element>' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
export const MyPage: NextPage = async ({}) => {
  const userCredit = await getCredit(user.id);
```

Comment: Have checked this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76446101/what-type-should-return-a-server-side-component?

Comment: Does not answer the question in that thread @YoussoufOumar

Answer (score 0):

You Can use FC Like this

```
export const MyPage: Fc<MyPageProps>= async ({}) => {
```

const userCredit = await getCredit(user.id);

Answer (score 0):

Someone else's help me, apparently `FunctionComponent` works with RSCs/Async Components with `typescript` version 5.1.0 or higher and `@types/react` at 18.2.0 or higher